# Not detecting empty/null lines

Tags: c#

So I am trying to use a config file that will have commonly used data each time you open the program, in this example a name which will be on the first line.
The issue is that I want to make sure that each individual line that would store something (name = line1, dob = line2) cant be empty. But it doesnt seem to notice that the config is empty.

```
Console.WriteLine("Finding config");
var folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\imsammstbot";
var filePath = folderPath + "\\tbot.config";
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Config loading");
    Console.WriteLine(filePath);
    string[] cfgdata = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    Console.WriteLine(cfgdata);
    int linenum = 0;
    foreach (string line in cfgdata)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Config empty\nGenerating new config file");
            newcfg();
        }
        if (++linenum == 1) { string name = line; }
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No config found\nGenerating new config file");
    newcfg();
}
```

Comment: But this code, at the first empty line, creates a new configuration file. It doesn't check what kind of line is reading. What lines are expected to be present in the configuration file and does it matter if these lines are not in the expected order?

Comment: Further up in the code when the config is originally created (the newcfg function)
the lines are organised where the first is name second being x third being y and so on, later on i can easily decode that as they are in order. I just want to make sure that if something goes wrong there is no way the cfg could be empty or broken when the code is launched.

Comment: You might find something like this useful: https://github.com/toml-lang/toml - it's kind of like an .htaccess file for .NET

Comment: If you want to check if the file is missing some info you need to read the whole file and then check against a list of expected key=value pair if something is not there. The presence of an empty line doesn't mean that there are some information missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foreach` only runs if there is at least 1 line. To create a new config when there are **0 lines**, you need to do an explicit check + corresponding action for that:

```
string[] cfgdata = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
if (cfgdata.Length == 0) newcfg();
```

You probably also need to provide further handling after that, e.g. if you want the newly created config to be used, then you'd need to also read the newly created file:

```
string[] cfgdata = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
if (cfgdata.Length == 0)
{
    newcfg();
    cfgdata = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    if (cfgdata.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Config file is empty, despite just creating a new one.")
    }
}
foreach (string line in cfgdata)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: new cfg adds to it anyways 
entername:
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                goto name;
            }

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: It usually doesn't hurt to be careful and do checks instead of assuming things will be OK. I make no assumptions about what `newcfg()` does (how could I even know?), it checks what it needs and throws an Exception if it did not get what it wants.